# References for topological quantum field theory

Tags: reference-request, topological-quantum-field-theory

I have been studying TQFTs and I am mainly reading

- Lurie's proof of the cobordism hypothesis: https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/papers/cobordism.pdf
- Walker's notes: https://canyon23.net/math/tc.pdf

However, neither of them are completely rigorous. As Lurie mentions on his homepage, his paper is an exposition. Has this proof been completely rigorously done anywhere? Also, I was very much enjoying Walker's notes, but they aren't complete. Are there any references that introduce TQFTs and explain how the definition of Extended TQFTs as $\left(\infty,n\right)$-functors comes up?

Comment: "Has this proof been completely rigourously done anywhere?": No, definitely not.  Calaque and Scheimbauer in their paper do give a rigorous definition of the symmetric monoidal (∞,n)-category of bordisms.  But there is nothing beyond.

Comment: Ayala-Francis write the proof assuming a result on factorization homology: https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.02240

Comment: @ThiKu, I found it quite hard to read the Ayala-Francis paper. What do I need to read before it? I.e., What are the prereqs?

Comment: I have no idea. I just wanted to hint you to that paper, which seems to be the state of the art.